# Create list of records and insert them later PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I need to control who and when entered each subpage, and insert this information into MySQL. I have MYSQL table which will get the information(userid,subpage,subpageid, datetime).

```
function logstore(){
global $DB, $USER, $CFG;


$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https')
=== FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script;

$newsurl = $CFG->wwwroot.'/news/view.php';
$produrl = $CFG->wwwroot.'/prod/view.php';
$materialurl = $CFG->wwwroot.'/material/index.php';


$datetime = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$records = new stdClass();
$records->userid = $USER->id;
if($currentUrl == $newsurl){
    $records->activity = 'news';
    $records->activityid = $_GET['id'];
}elseif ($currentUrl == $produrl){
    $records->activity = 'prod';
    $records->activityid = $_GET['id'];
}
elseif ($currentUrl == $materialurl){
    $records->activity = 'material';
    $records->activityid = $_GET['id'];
}

$records->datetime = $datetime;

$DB->insert_record('logstore', $records);}
```

Im calling this function on top of /news/view.php, /prod/view.php, /material/index.php.

Its working fine, but i need to optimize it a little. Is there any way i can insert those records when DB is free, or create list and insert them each hour?

//edit

I tried INSERT DELAYED but its not working with my DB :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way in Moodle/PHP to delay queries till the DB is free. "INSERT DELAY" is depracated in latest MySQL as you can see here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html
I can suggest two options:

1. Check your DB performance using http://mysqltuner.pl - maybe more memory/cache can help in performance.
2. Use another server for this log - so the load will be distributed on more servers.